# Magento 1.9: Change product order and direction on load?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-sorting

I need on load product order newest and order desc , right now I need to filter it manually and for direction I need to click on arrow twice at product listing....Is there any way to do it programmatically ?

can u change following of catalog/product/list.phtml...that i get **newest** product and in **desc** **order** ?

```
$_productCollection->clear()
                    ->getSelect()
                    ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER)
                    ->joinLeft(array('cpei'=>'catalog_product_entity_int'),     'e.entity_id = cpei.entity_id AND cpei.attribute_id = 197 AND cpei.store_id = 0', 'cpei.value as product_on_top' )
                    ->order(array('product_on_top DESC', 'price_index.min_price ASC', 'final_price ASC'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the direction from layout XML of your theme.

Below is the code of the `local.xml` file for your reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <!-- Change default direction for simple searches -->
    <catalogsearch_result_index>
        <reference name="search_result_list">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>

    <!-- Change default direction for advanced searches -->
    <catalogsearch_advanced_result>
        <reference name="search_result_list">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_advanced_result>

    <!-- Change default direction for a category without layered navigation -->
    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>

    <!-- Change default direction for a category with layered navigation -->
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>

    <!-- Change default direction for category with ID 3 -->
    <CATEGORY_3>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action>                                   
        </reference>
    </CATEGORY_3>
</layout>
```

Also, you can add layout XML as a Custom Design of your category in the admin. This setting will overwrite the local.xml configuration.

You can use the below code to get the list of products from a store.

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->load();
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){
   echo $_product->getName();
}
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: This change the arrow direction but what i need is when it clicked can you see change in url  "?dir=desc&order=product_id" this is what i need on load.

Comment: For this, you need to override the product collection and make set order to newest. I've updated my answer for your refrence.

Comment: Will you help me or suggest me any link for it ?

Comment: OK, let me check and revert you back regarding the same.

Comment: You can try this to override product collection on the category page and add your customizations there https://www.magemonkeys.com/overriding-model-in-magento-1-9-x/.

Comment: Sumit's answer should be marked as the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

just add below code in catalog/product/list.phtml

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_productCollection->clear()
                ->getSelect()
                //->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER)
                //->joinLeft(array('cpei'=>'catalog_product_entity_int'),     'e.entity_id = cpei.entity_id AND cpei.attribute_id = 197 AND cpei.store_id = 0', 'cpei.value as product_id' )
                ->order(array('product_id DESC'));
$_category  = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
```